# How to pass variable ids to statement.Query() in golang?

Tags: go, sqlx

I have this query in postgres which queries 1 or n users based on the parameters passed:

```
select name, phone from clients where id in ('id1','id2')
```

Now when I try to use this at golang I'm having problems approaching how to pass this type of variable arguments to the statement.Query() function:

```
ids := []string{"0aa6c0c5-e44e-4187-b128-6ae4b2258df0", "606b0182-269f-469a-bb29-26da4fa0302b"}
rows, err := stmt.Query(ids...)
```

This throws error: `Cannot use 'ids' (type []string) as type []interface{}`

When I check in source code query it can receive many variables of type interface:

```
func (s *Stmt) Query(args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error) {
    return s.QueryContext(context.Background(), args...)
}
```

If I do this manually it works:

```
rows, err := stmt.Query("0aa6c0c5-e44e-4187-b128-6ae4b2258df0", "606b0182-269f-469a-bb29-26da4fa0302b")
```

But of course I need the args to be 1 or many more, and dynamically generated.

I'm using Sqlx lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we can see on the `Query()` method scheme and also from the error message, the method requires an argument in `[]interface{}` type.

```golang
func (s *Stmt) Query(args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error) {
    return s.QueryContext(context.Background(), args...)
}
```

In your code, the `ids` variable hold `[]string` data. Change it to `[]interface{}` so it'll meet `Query()` requirements, then it'll work.

```golang
ids := []interface{}{
    "0aa6c0c5-e44e-4187-b128-6ae4b2258df0",
    "606b0182-269f-469a-bb29-26da4fa0302b",
}
rows, err := stmt.Query(ids...)
```

Comment: As relevant 4 years later! Thank you!