# Passing an array of values as a parameter to a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, go

I have a sql query like

```
SELECT SOME_FIELD FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID_FIELD IN ("abc", "def", "...", ...)
```

And an array that i need to pass as a parameter

```
p := []interface{"abc", "def", "blah", "foo"}
```

I prepare the statement:

```
stmt, err := conn.Prepare("SELECT SOME_FIELD FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID_FIELD IN (:1)")
rows, err := stmt.Query(p) // <- this complains that I pass an array as a value
```

I know that i can convert that array into a comma separated string of quoted values, but i wonder if there is a better way of passing an array of values as a parameter to a query

For moderators who closed my question previously: There is a similar question [How to pass variable ids to statement.Query() in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791692/how-to-pass-variable-ids-to-statement-query-in-golang) but it is **not** the same. The answer to that question suggests unpacking the array when passing to the Query, like `stmt.Query(...p)` - but this will not work in my case as this will be treated as a number of parameters instead of one array parameter